# Чекбоксы в массиве

Tags: php

Не один раз видел, что в форме у всех чекбоксов одно имя `name="check[]"`. Судя по всему, это массив. Как успешно принять его по посту и вывести в цикле через обычный оператор echo? Ну или может есть документация где-нибудь на этот счет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['check'])){
      $check=$_POST['check'];
      foreach ($check as $ch)
      {
          echo $ch.'<br />';
      }

  }
?>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Вот как то так. Вообще полезная штука передавать значения формы массивом, потом легче обрабатывать и собирать значения. Можно использовать многомерные массивы. name="check[test1][]",name="check[test2][]".
Чтоб посмотреть что забираешь из поста - используй функцию print_r, она все наглядно выведет